# FreeDOS invalid syntax for /f

Tags: cmd.exe, ms-dos, freedos

I got a script that uses `for /f` in Windows. However, FreeDOS doesn't seem to support the syntax `/f` and it is only supported in Windows emulated cmd.

```
for /f "tokens=4" %%i in ('all.bat') do set RESULT=%%i
```

This commands tells it to pick the fourth word and set it as a variable. I've tested it in cmd and it works, but now I need to put it into a bootable FreeDOS USB stick.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use a FreeDOS boot stick?

Comment: Sorry, it is a typo. I'm using FreeDOS but it doesn't support the /F syntax which apparently only works in cmd. I need to grep a line and set it as a variable.

Comment: If your question is wrong, then [edit] it to correct it.

Comment: @lbanz: Is an MS-DOS USB stick not an option?

Answer (score 1):

According to [FreeDOS Help](http://help.fdos.org/en/), the `for` command runs a specified command for each file in a set of files. Does not appear additional switches like `/F` to run it against the results of another command...